# Problems with generate random numbers when constructor is called with no arguments

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to create a Powerball simulator with classes called `PowerballTicket` and `PowerballLottery`. For the `PowerballTicket`, if the constructor is called with no arguments it will need to generate 6 random numbers (like the quickpick option in the real Powerball). What I have so far is

```
PowerballTicket::PowerballTicket(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6)
{
    RandomNumber randNum (1, 69);
    x1 = randNum.random();
    do {
        x2 = randNum.random();
    }while (x1 == x2);
    do {
        x3 = randNum.random();
    }while (x3 == x1 || x3 == x2);
    do {
        x4 = randNum.random();
    }while (x4 == x1 || x4 == x2 || x4 == x3);
    do {
        x5 = randNum.random();
    }while (x5 == x1 || x5 == x2 || x5 == x3 || x5 == x4);
    RandomNumber randNumPower (1, 23);
    mpowerball = randNumPower.random();
    mball1 = x1;
    mball2 = x2;
    mball3 = x3;
    mball4 = x4;
    mball5 = x5;
    mpowerball = x6;
}

int PowerballTicket::getball1()
{
    return mball1;
}

int PowerballTicket::getball2()
{
    return mball2;
}

int PowerballTicket::getball3()
{
    return mball3;
}

int PowerballTicket::getball4()
{
    return mball4;
}

int PowerballTicket::getball5()
{
    return mball5;
}

int PowerballTicket::getpowerball()
{
    return mpowerball;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to have a ticket with 6 valid random numbers and along with accessor methods for each, and also I'm not sure how to switch between when valid arguments are called in the constructor and no arguments called in the constructor.

`RandomNumber` is a class that generates random numbers and I'm positive it works.

Comment: Your constructor that takes the arguments is also the one that generates random numbers.

Comment: This constructor takes six arguments and discards them. What's the point? And what do you want the constructor to do differently with no arguments?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to have either 6 numbers entered by the user or if no argument is called the ticket will generate 6 random numbers instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this is the right way to have a ticket with 6 valid random numbers and along with accessor methods for each, and also I'm not sure how to switch between when valid arguments are called in the constructor and no arguments called in the constructor.

The easiest is to differentiate between the two conditions via two constructors. Use a default constructor to construct the ticket from generated random numbers, and a non-default to use the 6 numbers provided by the user.

What you have so far cannot be called with no numbers. The constructor as provided cannot be used as a default constructor. If default arguments are provided (e.g. in the class definition) for `x1` to `x6`, then it could, but the code doesn't hint at that.

The original code overwrites the provided numbers, there would be little point in doing that, either the numbers should be used, or they should be generated.

```
// default constructor...
PowerballTicket::PowerballTicket()
: mball1(0), mball2(0), mball3(0), mball4(0), mball5(0), mpowerball(0)
// you could exclude the above initialisations, the will be written to below
{
    // generate the random numbers
    RandomNumber randNum (1, 69);
    mball1 = randNum.random();
    do {
        mball2 = randNum.random();
    }while (mball1 == mball2);
    do {
        mball3 = randNum.random();
    }while (mball3 == mball1 || mball3 == mball2);
    do {
        mball4 = randNum.random();
    }while (mball4 == mball1 || mball4 == mball2 || mball4 == mball3);
    do {
        mball5 = randNum.random();
    }while (mball5 == mball1 || mball5 == mball2 || mball5 == mball3 || mball5 == mball4);
    RandomNumber randNumPower (1, 23);
    mpowerball = randNumPower.random();
}

PowerballTicket::PowerballTicket(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6)
: mball1(x1), mball2(x2), mball3(x3), mball4(x4), mball5(x5), mpowerball(x6)
{
    // use the numbers provided
}
```

The default constructor does the generation of the numbers, the non-default uses the provided numbers for the objects members.

To use the code;

```
PowerballTicket myNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // non-default constructor
PowerballTicket generatedNumbers; // default constructor
```

Comment: The initializations to `(0)` are redundant because you always assign a value later

Comment: I know, but I like to run the initialisation anyway in this case. The exceptions of `RandomNumber` are unknown and as sample code, I wanted the consistency between the constructors.

Answer (score -1):

Create two constructor 1 parameterized and 1 empty

If empty constructor is called  create 6 random number and call parameterized constructor

```
PowerballTicket::PowerballTicket()
{
    RandomNumber randNum (1, 69);
    x1 = randNum.random();
    do {
        x2 = randNum.random();
    }while (x1 == x2);
    do {
        x3 = randNum.random();
    }while (x3 == x1 || x3 == x2);
    do {
        x4 = randNum.random();
    }while (x4 == x1 || x4 == x2 || x4 == x3);
    do {
        x5 = randNum.random();
    }while (x5 == x1 || x5 == x2 || x5 == x3 || x5 == x4);
    RandomNumber randNumPower (1, 23);
    mpowerball = randNumPower.random();
    PowerballTicket(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, mpoerBall);
}

PowerballTicket::PowerballTicket(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6)
{
 //constructor already have value do what you want
    mball1 = x1;
    mball2 = x2;
    mball3 = x3;
    mball4 = x4;
    mball5 = x5;
    mpowerball = x6;

}
```

Comment: `PowerballTicket(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, mpoerBall);` creates a temporary object (it doesn't "call another constructor" on the same object)

Comment: we can use this(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5, mpoerBall);

Comment: No you can't do that either.  You could make a third function which both the constructors call, or (more simply) just assign the members